# javascript visit element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so I have something like this -

```
<a href="link..." class="text-box-a-href" >
<div class="text-box">
<h4>text...</h4>
<p> text....</p>
<span> date.</span>
</div>
</a>
```

What I need is, if someone clicks on link with class="text-box-a-href" it automatically adds class .visited to h4.
Something like this -

```
  $('.text-box-a-href').click(function() {

    var clicked_element;

    clicked_element = $(this);

    $(clicked_element).children('h4').addClass('visited');

    });
```

But nothing happens. On homepage I got like 10000 elements with  so you know.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't just using `a:visited h4 {}` in the CSS be simpler?

Comment: do you have multiple href that having same class.

Comment: @Quentin: You should totally write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do. But the page will just reload using that script. The class will get added, then the page reloads and the DOM get's rebuilt.

```
$('.text-box-a-href').click(function()
{

    $(this).find('h4').addClass('visited');

    return false; // Without this the page will just reload?

});
```

Comment: Ah, the h4 is a child of the anchor as there is an extra div. Change the `children` to `find` as in my updated answer

Comment: It is recommended to use `preventDefault()` instead of `return: false`  for cases like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false